# Rails Controller Method Not Reloading Page After Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, authentication, render

So I've built an authentication method which acts as a before filter for the other methods in the controller. Basically, I would like the method to redirect to the root path if the user is not logged in. Here is my authenticate_user! before filter method:

```
def authenticate_user!
      unless current_user
        flash[:notice] = "Your session has ended. Please login again."
        render js: "window.location.pathname = '#{root_path}'"
      end
end
```

The problem I'm having is that the window itself is not reloading, but rather the content element within the page and with the text displayed: "window.location.pathname = '/'". I'm not able to use a redirect_to (I found a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201351/rails-render-javascript-shows-text)) because it only seems to send a certain content element back to the root_path (while elements like the navbar remain the same). This is why I've been looking for a full window reload. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT with server log**:

```
Started GET "/projects/editHeader?fileName=test.csv" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-04 10:37:21 -0400
Processing by ProjectsController#editHeader as TEXT
  Parameters: {"fileName"=>"test.csv"}
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/projects/headerDataPreview?fileId=NaN" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-04 10:37:21 -0400
Processing by ProjectsController#headerDataPreview as TEXT
  Parameters: {"fileId"=>"NaN"}
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 2):

With ajax request you need to specify request type in the before_filter method

change your `authenticate_user!` method to

```
def authenticate_user
  unless current_user
    if request.xhr? # if its a ajax request then redirect with javascript
      flash.keep[:notice] = 'Bla bla bla' # keeps the flash message for next request
      render :js => "window.location = '#{root_path}'"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Bla bla bla"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any change with this solution; it just brings the screen to a blank page with the text "window.location = '\'".

Comment: Can you post your server log? In my current project I am using the same code and it works fine.

Comment: Massive gratitude for
`render :js =>`
Should be marked correct

Answer (score 0):

First of all - it's bad practise to put js in controller. Do not mix client scripts with server processed controllers. And about you problem - why dont you just use rails redirect?

```
def authenticate_user!
  unless current_user
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Your session has ended. Please login again."
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem with redirect_to is that the entire screen is not changing--only the inner content element. So the navbar sticks to the screen even though I want the user to be brought to a login splash page without a navbar.